# iOS convert date to local time zone?

Tags: ios, objective-c, date

I know this is a very question and asked multiple times before.But this is something i get stuck every time.
Now, i want to convert a date string from web service which is in Argentina local zone(`UTC-3:0`) and want to convert this that to device local time zone(Suppose `UTC+5:30`). Here is my code

```
-(NSDate *)getLocaDateStringFromDate:(NSString *)sourceDate andSourceTime:(NSString *)sourceTime
{
//sourceDate is @"2015-10-16"; and sourceTime is @"00:00:00"
    static NSDateFormatter* df = nil;
    if (!df) {
        df = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
        df.dateFormat = @"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss";
    }
    NSString* source = [sourceDate stringByAppendingString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@" %@", sourceTime]];
    NSTimeZone *sourceZone = [NSTimeZone timeZoneWithAbbreviation:@"ART"];
    [df setTimeZone: sourceZone];
    NSDate *ds = [df dateFromString:source];
     NSLog(@"sourceZone time is %@" , [df stringFromDate: ds]);//sourceZone time is 2015-10-16 00:00:00, correct!

    NSTimeZone *localTimeZone = [NSTimeZone systemTimeZone];
    [df setTimeZone: localTimeZone];
      NSLog(@"local time is %@" , [df stringFromDate: ds]);//local time is 2015-10-16 08:30:00,, correct

    NSString* str = [df stringFromDate: ds];
    return [df dateFromString:str]; //this return 2015-10-16 03:00:00 +0000, why? 
}
```

My question is that why my method return date in `UTC`, regardless of my time zone set to `systemTimeZone`. I get correct string but date is incorrect.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: [NSDate](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDate_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40003641)

Comment: Please read comments in my code for better understanding. I'm able to convert source date to local time zone in string, but my problem is how i convert this date string back to NSDate object in local time zone?

Answer (score 3):

1.) First, create an `NSDateFormatter` to get the `NSDate` sent from the server.

```
NSDateFormatter* dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'"];
```

2.) Convert the date string to a `NSDate`.

```
NSDate* sourceDate = [dateFormatter dateFromString:dateString];
```

3) Specify ,Local and Destination timezone in which you want to convert your date.

For getting timezone of your source date:

```
NSTimeZone* sourceTimeZone = [NSTimeZone timeZoneWithAbbreviation:@"GMT"];
```

For getting User timezone :

```
NSTimeZone* destinationTimeZone = [NSTimeZone systemTimeZone];
```

4.) Calculate the inverval between source timezone and user timezone as given bellow:

```
NSInteger sourceGMTOffset = [sourceTimeZone secondsFromGMTForDate:sourceDate];
    NSInteger destinationGMTOffset = [destinationTimeZone secondsFromGMTForDate:sourceDate];
    NSTimeInterval interval = destinationGMTOffset - sourceGMTOffset;

    NSDate* destinationDate = [[NSDate alloc] initWithTimeInterval:interval sinceDate:sourceDate];
```

5.) Now, create an `NSDateFormatter` for formatting date in which you want to show.

```
NSDateFormatter* dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
 [dateFormat setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone systemTimeZone]];
 [dateFormat setDateFormat:@"M/d/yy 'at' h:mma"];
 NSString* localTime = [dateFormat stringFromDate:destinationDate];
 NSLog(@"localTime:%@", localTime);
```

Hope it is useful for you :)

Comment: iI want to know what is wrong in my code?please read comments in my code.

Comment: Still not getting correct date, it's now 2015-10-16 11:30:00 +0000,  i put inputs and time zone are same as my question.

Comment: Thanks for this great help, but i still having an issue, i tried your code and can get correct destination date string (same thing with my code ),but i need it back in NSDate object. can you please add one final step to your example how do i get correct local date, from localTime string?

Comment: what is your local time..please give me

Comment: Sorry, i was away. my source(UTC-3:00, Abbreviation is "ART") dateString is @"2015-10-16 00:00:00" and destination(UTC+5:30, Abbreviation is "IST") date should be "2015-10-16 08:30:00", if i use date format as "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss".

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/92496/discussion-between-bharat-and-maulik).

Comment: @Bharat see my chat & replay

Comment: @Maulik This is really great help, I'm facing same issue. I followed all steps provided by you. Still i'm facing some issue with destination date, It's returning date with difference of 5 minutes. Can you please help me for this.